# Looping through multiple choice questions

Tags: python

I am working on a quiz to help me study for the a+ certification as well as helping me work on Python.  What I"m trying to do is loop through multiple choice questions while keeping my code clean and without repeating myself. I have a couple of questions programmed already, but I'd like advice on cleaning it up.  I've looked all over the interwebs and find lacking information on this specific thing.  I'd like to be able to loop through the questions without having to call each question method at the bottom.  Thanks for any help.  Here's my code:

```
answer = 0
correct = ""


def getAnswer():

    print "\n"
    prompt = ">"
    rawAnswer = raw_input(prompt)
    userAnswer = rawAnswer.upper()
    print "\n"

    if userAnswer == correct:
        print "That is correct!!! \n\n"
        print "***************************************************************\n"
        global answer
        answer += 1
    else:
        print "That was wrong"


def clrscreen():
    print ("\n" * 100)


def question1():
        print """Which of the following connector types is used by fiber-optic cabling?"

          Select the correct answer:

          A. LC
          B. RJ45
          C. RG-6
          D. RJ11"""
    enter code here
        global correct
        correct = "A"
        getAnswer()


def question2():
        print """Which protocol uses port 53?

          Select the correct answer:

          A. FTP
          B. SMTP
          C. DNS
          D. HTTP """

        global correct
        correct = "C"
        getAnswer()


def question3():
        print """You are making your own network patch cable. You need to attach an RJ45 plug to the end of a twisted-pair cable. Which tool should you use?

          Select the correct answer:

          A. Tone and probe kit
          B. Cable tester
          C. Crimper
          D. Multimeter"""

        global correct
        correct = "C"
        getAnswer()

def question4():
        print """Which port number does HTTP use?

          Select the correct answer:

          A. 21
          B. 25
          C. 80
          D. 110"""

        global correct
        correct = "C"
        getAnswer()

def question5():
        print """What device connects multiple computers together in a LAN?

          Select the correct answer:

          A. Modem
          B. Router
          C. Switch
          D. Firewall"""

        global correct
        correct = "C"
        getAnswer()

def question6():
        print """What is the name of a wireless network referred to as?

          Select the correct answer:

          A. SSID
          B. WPA
          C. DMZ
          D. DHCP"""

        global correct
        correct = "A"
        getAnswer()

question1()
clrscreen()
question2()
clrscreen()
question3()
clrscreen()
question4()
clrscreen()
question5()
clrscreen()
question6()
clrscreen()


score = round(answer/6.0 * 100)
print "Your score was ", score, "%"
print "\n"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than a function for reach question, you should be using a list or dictionary.  Consider the following:

```
questions = [ {prompt, [list of choices], correct answer index}, ... ]
```

so an example could be:

```
questions = [ {'prompt':"What is 2 + 2?", 'choices': [3, 4, 5], 'answer_index': 1},
              {'prompt':"What is 2 + 3?", 'choices': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'answer_index': 2} ]
```

Then you can go through them all like so:

```
for q in questions:
    print(q['prompt'])
    for i, c in enumerate(q['choices']):
        print(chr(97 + i) + ':', c)
    response = input("enter your answer:\n>>> ")
    print('The correct answer is:', chr(97 + q['answer_index']), '\n\n\n')
```

When I run that (and put in the answers) I get:

```
What is 2 + 2?
a: 3
b: 4
c: 5
enter your answer:
>>> b
The correct answer is: b 



What is 2 + 3?
a: 3
b: 4
c: 5
d: 6
e: 7
enter your answer:
>>> c
The correct answer is: c
```

Comment: Would that also work with what I have as far as a scoring system and the if functions to check if the given answer is right?

Comment: All you would need to do is ask for their answer, store it, and compare it to the correct answer.  If score is important to you, you might consider storing the answer index, rather than the answer, then printing out the choices with their index.  Will make checking the answer trivial that way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I also would like to be able to type a, b, c, or d for the answer instead of the string.  I've been looking for a little while, but I can't find how to set the answers to a variable instead of a string inside of that dictionary properly.

Comment: I edited my answer to add letter indices.  Change the 97 to 65 if you want capital letters.  Then if you need to keep track of score, just add a new variable, and compare the right answer with the input answer.